# Component renders data after refreshing page

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been trying to make jwt based authentication web but I got a problem. After a user logged in with username and password, it will set accessToken to localStorage and navigate to home page which will render the user name but it only display user name when I refresh the page.
My *app-component.html*

```
<ul>
<li><a routerLink="/home">Home</a></li>  
<li><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
<li><a routerLink="/register">Register</a></li>
<li><a routerLink="/logout">Log out</a></li> </ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My *login-component.ts*

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
      authRequest:AuthenticationRequest={
        username:"",
        password:"",
      };
      errorMessage:string ="";
    
      constructor(private jwtService:JwtClientService,
                  private router: Router) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      public login(authRequest:AuthenticationRequest){
        let resp = this.jwtService.authenticate(authRequest);
        resp.subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', data.refreshToken);
          },
          error: (error) => {
            this.errorMessage = error;
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      }
    
      onSubmit():void{
        this.login(this.authRequest);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
    }
```

My *home-component.ts*

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
  username:any;
  errorMessage:string = "";

  constructor(private jwtService: JwtClientService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getCurrentUserAccess(localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
  }


  public getCurrentUserAccess(token:any){
    let resp = this.jwtService.currentUserAccess(token);
    resp.subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.response = data
      },
      error: err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.errorMessage = err
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My *home.component.html*

```
<h1 *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</h1>
<hr>
<br>
<h1 style="color: red">User name: {{response}}</h1>
```

My *jwt-client.service.ts*

```
public authenticate(request:AuthenticationRequest){
    return this.http.post<AuthenticationResponse>(`${AUTH_API}/auth/authenticate`, request)
        .pipe(
          catchError((err)=>{
            console.log("Error handled by Service..." + err.status)
              return throwError(()=> new Error(err.error.message));
          })
        );
  }

  public currentUserAccess(token:any){
    let tokenStr = 'Bearer '+token;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", tokenStr);
    //console.log(headers +' '+ tokenStr)
    return this.http.get(`${AUTH_API}/auth/current-user`, {headers: headers, responseType: "text" as "json"})
     ;
  }
```

Comment: You are saying you are displaying user name and on refresh it is only displaying userName, your question is not clear can you elaborate more.

Comment: What's your login-component.html? Besides, Call `this.router.navigate(['/home']);` right after calling `localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', data.refreshToken);` (in the same `next:` block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resp.subscribe({ // <== This is async code
          next: (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', data.refreshToken);
          },
          error: (error) => {
            this.errorMessage = error;
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
```

And here you call `this.router.navigate()` synchronously

```
onSubmit(): void {
  this.login(this.authRequest);
  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

Instead, call `this.router.navigate()` from the `next` block inside `login` method